# Set position in file and cannot read it back

Tags: c++, stream, fstream

I create a file, I move both read and write position to 5, I read the position back, and what I get is an invalid position. Why?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string fname = "test.txt";

    {
        fstream fs(fname);
        fs << "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    }

    fstream fs(fname);
    streamoff p = 5;

    fs.seekg(p, ios_base::beg);
    fs.seekp(p, ios_base::beg);

    const streamoff posg = fs.tellg();
    const streamoff posp = fs.tellp();

    cerr << posg << " = " << posp << " = " << p << " ???" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

> -1 = -1 = 5 ???

Comment: Please examine the state of your stream.  You may need to clear the state before you reposition.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews no it's not that matter but as you can see opening fails as long as opening for read and write a not-existing file. file must be existing otherwise he should add opening flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not creating file correctly so you are opening a file for read and write without specifying the options for opening in this case it consider the file already exists thus it fails to open.

- the second mistake you pass a string to fstream's open function which takes a const string the result it fails so you convert it to char* with string's c_str
  member function.

the law a thumb is always check if opening was successful or not.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string fname = "test.txt";

    fstream fs(fname.c_str(), ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary | ios::trunc);
    if(fs.fail())
        cout << "Failed to open file" << endl;
    fs << "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    streamoff p = 5;

    fs.seekg(p, ios_base::beg);
    fs.seekp(p, ios_base::beg);

    const streamoff posg = fs.tellg();
    const streamoff posp = fs.tellp();

    cerr << posg << " = " << posp << " = " << p << " ???" << endl;

    fs.close();

    return 0;
}
```

- note if you don't my open flags (ios::trunc, out, in) just create manually a file named "test.txt" in your project directory.

Comment: Since C++11, it is possible to pass a non const string to an fstream ctor [[ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream)].

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your file is never written correctly in the first place, because you are using a `std::fstream`, which fails when opening a nonexistent file with its default mode of `ios::out|ios::in` (see [`std::basic_filebuf::open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) and the default parameters used with [`std::basic_fstream::open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open)).

To fix it, just use a `std::ofstream` instead of a `std::fstream` when writing the file:

```
{
  ofstream fs(fname);
  fs << "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
}
```